# SQL outer join issue for returning null records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Region VARCHAR(75))
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT distinct classname from x where class = 'y' and date = '12/31/2015'

SELECT *
FROM @Temp T LEFT OUTER JOIN x N ON N.Classname = T.Region where T.Region NOT LIKE '%Cash%'
AND N.[Code] = '785' 
AND N.Horizon = 'year'
AND N.[date] = '12/31/2015'
```

This must be returning all the class names from Temp including the ones which have no records in x. Atleast that's my intention. X without temp and same conditions, only returns the ones it has data for. I want all classnames from Temp which have no entries in X too. It still doesnt do that.

Cant solve it. Tried NOT EXISTS,Except and Outer apply. None of them work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the conditions on the second table into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Temp T LEFT OUTER JOIN
     x N
     ON N.Classname = T.Region AND
        N.[Code] = '785' AND
        N.Horizon = 'year' AND
        N.[date] = '2015-12-31'
WHERE T.Region NOT LIKE '%Cash%';
```

Assuming that `date` is stored as a date, use proper ISO standard date formats for your queries.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks Gordon.